# What distance should I use for edges weights in textrank algorithm

Tags: nlp

I found [this](https://github.com/davidadamojr/TextRank) python implementation on github with 400+ stars which use levenshtein distance between each nodes.

But [original paper (page 4)](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W04-3252) said:

> Next, all lexical units that pass the syntactic filter
>   are added to the graph, and an **edge is added between
>   those lexical units that co-occur within a window of N word**

So the question is: is levenshtein distance legit for this algorithm or better to rewrite with windowed edges?

Intuitively levenshtein distance must not work because it's not denote importance of word...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lib author said using lev-dist was just en experiment and might not work (and it really doesn't), but for some reason people use broken lib w/o questions ¯\_(ツ)_/¯